# Black layer over desktop

Tags: filemanager

After tweaking around with my file manager, somehow I got a black layer over me desktop. In the bottom and right side of my screen I can see part of my selected desktop background, but all the rest is black.

[image: background]

When I right click on the black part of the desktop a configuration window pops up named "This Panel" Version 1.1.2.

[image: this panel]

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

What did I mess up with?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Even though I think no one else had the aforementioned issue.. just in case that you face a similar problem I resolved it by uninstalling "Desktop Folder" application (after upgrading to 22.04).